# Create karaoke effect Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm starting Flutter. Does anyone know how to make the effect on image?

Karaoke Effect

[image: Karaoke Effect]

Answer (score 0):

you can use animated_text_kit package

https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Stack` to put a layer of red `Text` on top of a layer of white `Text`. And then use `ClipRect` to slowly show the top layer.

Basically:

```
Stack
[
  - ClipRect
    - Red Text
  - White Text
]
```

The most difficulty part is "time sync", i.e. to know the speed of the flow, because in a song, some words are gonna be much faster than other words. Tell us your plan of time sync, and I can further suggest which type of animation controller is best for this task.

Comment: I want to transfer color every single word during the t2s time of these words.